# Why can't my function handle a NaN value and throws "float' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe with a messy value columnn which I want to clean up. My dataframe looks like this:

```
d = {"Name": ["A", "B", "C"], "Value": ["2.45k", np.nan, "1.23"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Name  Value
  0    A  2.45k
  1    B    NaN
  2    C   1.23
```

Exploring the NaN row via `type(df.iloc[1,1])` tells me that `NaN` has type `float` and using `float(df.iloc[1,1])` keeps/returns `nan` without throwing any error.

So I've written a function to clean the column. It checks if there is a somehow suffix and in cases there is not, it returns the given value as type `float`:

```
def to_float(x):
    if x[-1] == "k":
        return float(x.rstrip("k")) * 1000
    else:
        return float(x)
```

But when calling:

```
B = to_float(df.iloc[1,1])
```

I am retrieving a Type error: `'float' object is not subscriptable` which I don't understand since `float(df.iloc[1,1])` basically works.

I need to assign the value to an attribute so just skipping NaN rows isn't an option.

I found out that I could wrap the whole function in a try/except statement, but there probably is a more elegant way to handle it?

Comment: This is the line with the error `x[-1]` when `x` is a float you can't subscript it. (`np.NaN[-1]` is the effective call)

Comment: So I basically just have to put the check for np.nan condition first to solve it?

Comment: I would say checking that `x` is of type `str` before slicing would be the clearer approach. But basically yes.

Comment: Yeah, better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
from numpy import nan
df['new'] = pd.eval(df.Value.str.replace('k','*1000'))
df
  Name  Value      new
0    A  2.45k  2450.00
1    B    NaN      NaN
2    C   1.23     1.23
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that this can work. The only problem is that this won't work for row3 since ``df.iloc[3,1]`` will return a string as well and won't get replaced.

Comment: @Christian after above do pd.to_numeric(df['new'] )

Comment: Ah, right. And if there are more than one to replace suffix variations? Probably a dict within replace()?

Comment: @Christian do `df.Value.replace({'k':'*1000','m':'*1000000'},regex = True)`

Answer (score 0):

According to Henry's comment to my question I included a type check:

```
def to_float(x):
    if type(x) != str:
        return x
    elif x[-1] == "k":
        return float(x.rstrip("k")) * 1000
    else:
        return float(x)
```